# passing an sql file with insert statements to a postgres database using java jdbc

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I would like to make an sql file with INSERT statements so I can update my postgres database and I was wondering how could I pass the sql file to my database using jdbc ?

Comment: you don't want to iterate through the file in java and execute each line as an insert statement?

Comment: No i would just like to pass the whole file if it is even possible to do it

Comment: So you just want to execute the line as it is? I don't think it's safe. Heard about XSS or SQL Injection?

Comment: No I am fairly new to database connectivity and sql for that matter. I would just like to pass the sql file so that all the statements in it could be executed at "once" like .read "sample.sql" in sqlite executes all of the statements from a "sample.sql" file.

Comment: You need to parse the file, split it into separate statement and then execute each statement through JDBC. The Postgres JDBC driver (or any other JDBC driver for that matter) does not support running scripts. The equivalent to SQLite's `.read sample.sql` is to run `psql -f sample.sql` using `ProcessBuilder`